# T/F $|f|=|g|$ a.e. $\Leftrightarrow f=g$ a.e. or $f=-g$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a measure space. Is it true that $$|f|=|g|\, \text{ a.e.} \Leftrightarrow f=g \,\text{ a.e. or} f=-g\, \text{ a.e.}? $$

I think this is false. Take for example $X=\{a,b \},S=\mathcal P(X),\mu=\#$ (the number of elements).

$f(a)=1,f(b)=-1,g(a)=1=g(b)$.

Is this example ok?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did: would you post this comment as an answer, just for the sake of OP to have an answer? Perhaps, adding another example (say for $S = \Bbb R$)

Comment: @Ilya: I think it would be more fitting if the OP posted an answer himself.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I agree.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: there was a discussion on meta before on this topic. As far as I remember, both ways are ok. However, I guess that in case OP provides a correct solution, it is still preferable to give an answer that e.g. provides an alternative solution.

Comment: Another example would be $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=|x|$ if $\mu(-\infty,0]=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that $|f|=|g|$ a.e. if and only if $f=hg$ a.e., where $h$ is a *unimodular* function, $|h|=1$ a.e. The function $h$ need not be constant, unless the measure space is very degenerate (all sets are either null or have null complement).

Indeed, we can take any measurable set $E$ with $\mu(E)>0$ and $\mu(X\setminus E)>0$; then define $f= 2\chi_E-1$ and $g=1$.